# completed or have completed undergraduate

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect

I have completed my undergraduate degree at Harvard.
Or
I completed my undergraduate degree at Harvard.

Which one is correct? The simple past variant or the present perfect one?

Comment: Use simple past unless there is context supporting the usage of a perfect tense.

Answer (score -1):

Both are correct. Which you would use depends on what you are trying to say.

**I completed my undergraduate education at Columbia in 1966** is a simple statement about an act in the distant past. The verb is in the simple **PAST.**

On the other hand, acts in the very recent past may be indicated by using the **PRESENT** perfect. **He has completed his undergraduate education at Harvard and will be going to Yale Law School soon** might be something a proud parent would say in the months intervening between a son's graduation from Harvard College and becoming a 1L in New Haven.